# How to replace "\n" but not ">\n" in a string

Tags: java, html, regex

Using Java how is it possible replace all `"\n"` but not `">\n"` with `"<br/>"`?

I need it because I want add a `"<br/>"` if I have a new line on plain text, but not if I have HTML.

Comment: @Pshemo: thank you. I was going crazy trying to read this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind).

```
String str = "\n>\n\n";

str = str.replaceAll("(?<!>)\n", "<br />");
```

This will match the `\n`, and then backtrack a character to ensure the preceding character wasn't a `>`.

Comment: NB: `replaceAll` returns a `String` with the replacements made.  It will not actually change `str`.